# Как задать в PlayerPrefs bool значение в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, bool

Как задать в PlayerPrefs bool значение в unity?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073236/how-to-save-bool-to-playerprefs-unity

Comment: Никак. Есть три возможности: сохранить строку, целое число, число с плавающей точкой. Bool можно сохранить, например, как число

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть всего три метода [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html):

- PlayerPrefs.SetInt(string s, int v)  —  PlayerPrefs.GetInt(string s)
- PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(string s, float v)  —  PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(string s)
- PlayerPrefs.SetString(string s, string v)  —  PlayerPrefs.GetString(string s)

Все они записывают значение `v` с ключом `s`, либо получают значение по ключу `s`.

Если вы хотите сохранить bool, то его надо выразить через int, float или string. Легче через int:

```
bool IntToBool (int n) 
    => n == 1;
int BoolToInt (bool b) 
    => (b ? 1 : 0);
```

После этого можно делать:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt([ключ], BoolToInt([bool значение])); // сохранение
IntToBool(PlayerPrefs.GetInt([ключ])); // чтение
```

Comment: `=> n == 1;` Неверно! Нужно писать инверсию, т.к. `true` это любое значение отличное от нуля.

Comment: @こきん "true это любое значение отличное от нуля". Я не обязан этому следовать! Я хочу, что 1=true, 0=false. А других чисел вообще быть не может,  потому что BoolToInt возвращает только 0 или 1. В рамках данной задачи такое соответствие работает. Если ТС будет выходить за эти рамки и использовать эти методы не только с PlayerPrefs, то да, возможно, нужно будет поменять, но в рамках исключительно данной задачи мой метод работает. Может он не соответствует признанным нормам, стандартам, но уж точно. **не** ваше резкое "Неверно!"